# How to position subcontainers so that they sit right on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I have a bar chart that includes 5 different sub-containers inside each with a different height and different color. The 'chicken' sub-container goes on the bottom of the bar, then on top of that should go the eggs sub-container, on top of that the pork sub-container, etc.

I can't figure out though how to get the eggs sub-container directly atop the chicken container with no margin between (I could add a bunch of divs but that seems like a clumsy solution).

Here's what it looks like (chicken is blue, eggs purple, etc) (note: the height of each sub-container is determined by Javascript)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="days">
<div class="days-container">
<div class="dairy"></div>
<div class="beef"></div>
<div class="pork"></div>
<div class="eggs"></div>
<div class="chicken"></div>
</div> <!-- end days-container-->
</div> <!-- end days -->
```

CSS:

```
 .days {
 float: left;
 height:330px;
 width: 1em;
}

.days-container {
position:relative;
height: 330px;
}

.chicken {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
background-color: #00AAFF;
width: 1em;
}

.eggs {
width: 1em;
????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position:absolute;`

They are block, su they are automaticly going 1 after an other : http://jsfiddle.net/XzU47/

Answer (score 0):

Your chicken container is being positioned at the bottom:

```
    position: absolute;  bottom:0;
```

of the days-container and eggs is not. If you want them all at the top remove the above statements from your CSS.